Do different orders on the same ordered field coincide up to isomorphism?
Ordered field means the field $F$ equipped with a totally order $>$, which satisfies
· $\forall x,y,z \in F, y > z \Longrightarrow x+y > x+z$;
· $\forall x,y \in F, x,y > 0 \Longrightarrow xy > 0$.
It is naturally to guess that
· if there are two orders $>_1, >_2$ on $F$ that both make $F$ become a ordered field, then we can give a isomorphism which maintians order relationship.
Is this proposition correct?
For example, $F = R(x)$ which consist of rational functions with real coefficient. We can consider $x$ as infinitesimal to give a totally order, or $x = \infty$ giving another order. The mapping $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is waht we desire.
My friend told me, someone haven told him that, I can refer the real field and unique extension theorem. But my friend and me don't know how to handle it.

It is not natural to guess this. Why should any two orders be so closely related? There are many counterexamples. Notice that your question is equivalent to: if two ordered fields have isomorphic underlying fields, are they isomorphic as ordered fields? Again, nothing you would expect to be true.

The answer is no, as a hint try out some non-Galois extensions of $\Bbb Q$ admitting distinct real embeddings
